# What is the meaning of "index of gpio"?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, gpio

I'm wondering what is the meaning of "Index of gpio".

This is what I see in the `of_gpio.h`

```
/**
* of_get_named_gpio() - Get a GPIO number to use with GPIO API
* @np:      device node to get GPIO from
* @propname:    Name of property containing gpio specifier(s)
* @index:   index of the GPIO
*
* Returns GPIO number to use with Linux generic GPIO API, or one of the 
  errno
* value on the error condition.
*/
static inline int of_get_named_gpio(struct device_node *np,
                                  const char *propname, int index)
{
    return of_get_named_gpio_flags(np, propname, index, NULL);
}
```

I can't really understand the meaning cause I can't see any function are using "int index".

Comment: *" I can't see any function are using "int index""* -- See 125 files   https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/ident/of_get_named_gpio

Answer (score 0):

Its the index into the list of gpios. When describing gpios in the device tree, you are always able to specify a list of gpio pins, its upto the individual driver whether it just needs a single pin or multiple ones.

Have a look at the [documentation](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/gpio/gpio.txt) which describes how to specify gpios generically:

> Nodes that makes use of GPIOs should specify them using one or more
>   properties, each containing a 'gpio-list':
>
> ```
> gpio-list ::= <single-gpio> [gpio-list]
> single-gpio ::= <gpio-phandle> <gpio-specifier>
> gpio-phandle : phandle to gpio controller node
> gpio-specifier : Array of #gpio-cells specifying specific gpio
>                  (controller specific)
> ```

A good example of a driver which uses a list of pins is the `gpio-matix-keyboard`, so in its [documentation](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/input/gpio-matrix-keypad.txt) there is the example:

```
row-gpios = <&gpio2 25 0
             &gpio2 26 0
             &gpio2 27 0>;
```

and the [code](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.14/source/drivers/input/keyboard/matrix_keypad.c#L453) which parses this:

```
for (i = 0; i < pdata->num_row_gpios; i++)
    gpios[i] = of_get_named_gpio(np, "row-gpios", i);
```